# Overlapping grayscale and RGB Images

Tags: image, matlab, colors, rgb, colormap

I would like to overlap two images, one grayscale and one RGB image. I would like to impose the RGB image on top of the grayscale image, but ONLY for pixels greater than a certain value. I tried using the `double` function in MATLAB, but this seems to change the color scheme and I cannot recover the original RGB colors. What should I do in order to retain the original RGB image instead of mapping it to one of the MATLAB colormaps? Below is my attempt at superimposing:

```
pixelvalues = double(imread('hello.png'));
PixelInt = mean(pixelvalues,3);
I1 = ind2rgb(Brightfield(:,:,1), gray(256)); %Brightfield
I2 = ind2rgb(PixelInt, jet(256)); %RGB Image
imshow(I2,[])
[r,c,d] = size(I2);
I1 = I1(1:r,1:c,1:d);
% Replacing those pixels below threshold with Brightfield Image
threshold = 70;

I2R = I2(:,:,1); I2G = I2(:,:,2); I2B = I2(:,:,3);
I1R = I1(:,:,1); I1G = I1(:,:,2); I1B = I1(:,:,3);

I2R(PixelInt<threshold) = I1R(PixelInt<threshold);
I2G(PixelInt<threshold) = I1G(PixelInt<threshold);
I2B(PixelInt<threshold) = I1B(PixelInt<threshold);
I2(:,:,1) = I2R; I2(:,:,2) = I2G; I2(:,:,3) = I2B;

h = figure;
imshow(I2,[])
```

**Original RGB Image:**

[image: Original RGB Image]

**Brightfield:**

[image]

**Overlay**:

[image: Overlay]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the content of `pixelvalues` what you show in your first image? If so, that image does not use a [`jet`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jet.html) colormap. It has pink and white values above the red values, whereas `jet` stops at dark red at the upper limits. When you take the mean of those values and then generate a new RGB image with [`ind2rgb`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html) using the `jet` colormap, you're creating an inherently different image. You probably want to use `pixelvalues` directly in generating your overlay, like so:

```
% Load/create your starting images:
pixelvalues = imread('hello.png');           % Color overlay
I1 = repmat(Brightfield(:, :, 1), [1 1 3]);  % Grayscale underlay
[r, c, d] = size(pixelvalues);
I1 = I1(1:r, 1:c, 1:d);

% Create image mask:
PixelInt = mean(double(pixelvalues), 3);
threshold = 70;
mask = repmat((PixelInt > threshold), [1 1 3]);

% Combine images:
I1(mask) = pixelvalues(mask);
imshow(I1);
```

Note that you may need to do some type conversions when loading/creating the starting images. I'm assuming `'hello.png'` is a [`uint8` RGB image](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-12468) and `Brightfield` is of type [`uint8`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html). If I load your first image as `pixelvalues` and your second image as `I1`, I get the following when running the above code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a mask and use it to combine the images:

`onionOrig = imread('onion.png');
onionGray = rgb2gray(onionOrig);
onionMask = ~(onionOrig(:,:,1)<100 & onionOrig(:,:,2)<100 & onionOrig(:,:,3)<100);

onionMasked(:,:,1) = double(onionOrig(:,:,1)) .* onionMask + double(onionGray) .* ~onionMask;
onionMasked(:,:,2) = double(onionOrig(:,:,2)) .* onionMask + double(onionGray) .* ~onionMask;
onionMasked(:,:,3) = double(onionOrig(:,:,3)) .* onionMask + double(onionGray) .* ~onionMask;

onionFinal = uint8(onionMasked);
imshow(onionFinal)`